# Send my currentPosition from android application to JavaServer

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm working an android application where I have to take some markers from java server and show that in a maps on a phone. This work very well, i have done java server and android application. Now, to complete that, i would like to pass my current position from andorid application to java server. How can i do that? I think i have to use AsynkTask. 
So, i would to pass to my java server "myLat" and "myLog"

`locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        myLat = location.getLatitude();
        myLong = location.getLongitude();`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AsynkTask allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
For sending your lat and long to server you have to use web Api.
first create a web api for receiving data to server and then use http://square.github.io/retrofit/,
Rxjava2
or the basic one https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html